# How to remove an item from a Xamarin Forms ListView?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I'm trying to remove items/rows from a `ListView` but the difficulty is that I need to also pass in some delegate or fire some event or something, so when a person clicks a button to remove that row, my code handles some other logic, elsewhere (eg. remove the item from the DB or whatever).

I have a custom control I made:

```
public class SportsTeam : StackLayout { .. }
```

Inside this control, one of the elements is a `ListView` which lists all the people in a sporting team.

```
var viewModel = teamMembers.Select(x => new SportsTeamViewModel(x));

return new ListView
{
    HasUnevenRows = true,
    ItemSource = viewModel,
    ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SportsTeamViewCell)); 
};
```

Inside the `SportsTeamViewCell` I have the following:

```
private Grid CreateContent()
{
    var grid = new Grid();
    // Setup row and column definitions.
    // Add items to the Grid 
    grid.Children.Add(...);

    var removeButton = RemoveButton;
    grid.Children.Add(removeButton);
    Grid.SetRowSpan(removeButton, 2);

    return grid;
}

private Button RemoveButton
{
    get
    {
        var button = new Button
        {
            Image = "Icons/remove.png"
        };

        return button;
    }
}
```

From here, I don't know how to make it so that the button fires an event or some delete could be passed in via the constructor, so some custom logic is performed against the individual cell/row/item that is to be removed.

Comment: Pass the Id of the Row to be deleted into click event handler of the RemoveButton.

Comment: How do I find the Id of the row to be deleted? Or can each row have another special Id which I give it? like some hidden magical id? Or the value of something else from the bound data? eg. the `Id` or `UserName` or whatever ....

Comment: Yes, you have to use the Bindings and bind your model's Id property to click event of button.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Here is what you could do :

This be my model class :

```
public class Item  
{  
   public string ItemName { get; set; }  
   public string ItemDetails { get; set; }  
}
```

And in my XAML or you can write this in code as well, bind to the `Command Parameter` of your Item template :

```
<Button Text="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemName}" Clicked="DeleteClicked"></Button>
```

Full Item Template will be like below :

```
<ListView.ItemTemplate>  
            <DataTemplate>  
               <ViewCell>  
                  <ViewCell.View>  
                     <StackLayout Orientation="Horizontal">  
                        <Label Text="{Binding ItemName}" HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" FontSize="30"></Label>  
                        <Button Text="Delete" CommandParameter="{Binding ItemName}" Clicked="DeleteClicked">        
                        </Button>  
                     </StackLayout>  
                  </ViewCell.View>  
               </ViewCell>  
            </DataTemplate>  
         </ListView.ItemTemplate>
```

And in you code file you can do this :

```
public void DeleteClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)  
{  
   var item = (Xamarin.Forms.Button)sender;  
   Item listitem = (from itm in allItems 
                    where itm.ItemName == item.CommandParameter.ToString() 
                    select itm)
                   .FirstOrDefault<Item>();  
   allItems.Remove(listitem);  
}
```

**IMPORTANT** : This would only delete the item from the bound collection. To delete it from the original list you need to use `ObservableCollection`

Here is the full source code of the explained scenario - [Handling Child Control Event in Listview using XAMARIN.FORMS](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/Blogs/48291/handling-child-control-event-in-listview-using-xamarin-forms.aspx).

Also the Tutorial - [How to handle Row selection and delete Button in Row For Custom ListView using Xamarin.Forms](http://mobilewits.com/blog/how-to-handle-row-selection-and-delete-button-in-row-for-custom-listview-using-xamarin-forms/) explain deletion from a `listview` as well.

Comment: Awesome @Rohit! This is the type of answer I was really hoping for :) I'll give this code a crack later on today. Thanks mate!

Comment: Hi @rohit - I've had a play with your code and I can't seem to understand it. Firstly, I get the `CommandParameter`. Fine. Secondly, I do _not_ want to put the code for `Clicked` _inside_ of my control. This is because I have no idea what this generic control will do, once clicked. I want to _pass_ the method to be handled, when clicked, _into_ this control. So the logic remains outside of this control :)

Comment: If you want the logic to be outside either you could subscribe to the click event by using [MessagingCenter](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/cross-platform/xamarin-forms/messaging-center/) or try to attach to the event yourself using .NET event handlers.

Comment: I'm trying to attach an event to my listview ... which is where i'm so stuck. The list view takes the `ItemTemplate = new DataTemplate(typeof(SportsTeamViewCell));` template. I just don't know how (or where) to attach my custom event... ???

Comment: Please have a look at Xamarin message center if you are trying to get events between controller and Viewmodel

Comment: what do you mean by itm I am getting Unknown identifier: itm

Comment: @ShwetaNandha - That is basic LINQ. Its to get the item based on the items in the array. If your question is different than what OP asked, please post another question. Also things might have changed in 3 years.

Comment: Just learning Xamarin for a class... you just helped me figure out something that I spent a couple of hours on. Thank you!!!

Answer (score 3):

I've found a similar approach and I want to share it. I filled the list with an `ObservableCollection<MyObject>`. Then I filled the CommandParameter with just `CommandParameter="{Binding .}"`. So I got the whole Object back. Then you can just cast the `CommandParameter`to your Object and remove it from the `ObservableCollection<MyObject>` List

XAML:

```
CommandParameter="{Binding .}"
```

Filling my List:

```
savingExpensesCollection = new ObservableCollection<SavingsExpensesEntry> ();
savingExpensesCollection .Add (new SavingsExpensesEntry ("1000 mAh Akku", "Dampfgarten", new DateTime (635808692400000000), 8.95));
savingExpensesCollection .Add (new SavingsExpensesEntry ("Cool-Mint Aroma", "Dampfgarten", new DateTime (635808692400000000), 3.95));
savingExpensesCollection .Add (new SavingsExpensesEntry ("Basis", "Dampfgarten", new DateTime (635808692400000000), 13.65));

savingExpensesList.ItemsSource = savingExpenses;
```

EventHandler:

```
void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender);
    SavingsExpensesEntry see ((SavingsExpensesEntry)menuItem.CommandParameter);
    savingExpensesCollection .Remove (see);
}
```

I've using a `MenuItem` but it's the same approach with a `Button`

Answer (score -1):

I just did using delete button

```
  public void OnDelete(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var mi = ((MenuItem)sender);

        PhotoViewModel photo= ((photoViewModel)mi.CommandParameter);
        photoModel.Remove(photo);
    }
```