# How can I delete an item from a listview?

Tags: xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I have a listview with data I don't know. I would like to delete a line after I press a button. The button is in the  of the listview.

My code:
Xaml:

```
<MenuItem Clicked="SupprimerPoste_Clicked" CommandParameter="{Binding .}" />
```

my List:

```
public static ObservableCollection<Data> listePosteNoteFrais = new ObservableCollection<Data>(); 
App.listePosteNoteFrais.Add(new Data { Numero = Label_Numero.Text, ... });
```

event button:

```
 private void SupprimerPoste_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
var menuItem = ((MenuItem)sender); 
Data delete ((Data)menuItem.CommandParameter 
App.listePosteNoteFrais.Remove(delete); 
}
```

Comment: Does the MenuItem in the every item of the listview? You need to make it bind a property of the Data class.

Comment: @LiyunZhang-MSFT Yes, when I press a long time on a line of my ListView, the menuItem appears. I added `public object Delete { get; set; }` in my Data.cs. I have many error in my buton event

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you can try to remove the item in the data list in the clicked event of the button. You can check the following case which shows how to delete the item in the listview.

Case:[How to remove an item from a Xamarin Forms ListView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32728535/how-to-remove-an-item-from-a-xamarin-forms-listview)

In addition, you can check the official document about how to use the observable collection as the listview's item resource.

Official document:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/listview/data-and-databinding

Comment: Please edit your answer and add the code to the question.@Olivia

Comment: What does the CommandParameter of the MenuItem bind? You can check whether the `Data delete`  in the clicked event is null or not. @Olivia

Comment: Thank you @Liyun Zhang - MSFT The link works !!!!